# Removing DragManager.acceptDragDrop() in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

Is there any opposite method for DragManager.acceptDragDrop(),like DragManager.removeDragDrop() which can be handled in dragExit event.any ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite of this:

```
DragManager.acceptDragDrop(component);
```

is this:

```
DragManager.acceptDragDrop(null);
```

Or just not call `DragManager.acceptDragDrop` at all, [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64595-7ff4) you can read this:

> If the drag data is not in a compatible format, do not call the DragManager.acceptDragDrop() method. If the event handler does not call this method, the user cannot drop the data and the drop target will not receive the dragOver, dragExit, and dragDrop events.

Comment: This is not working.I have to handle this in dragExit event.My situation is when the user drags and enter the component it should accept the drag and if the user doesnt drop and if he/she drags it out of the component dragExit should remove DragManager.acceptDragDrop() method.How to handle this??

Comment: To be honest I don't know how you can do this. And I don't even know why you must do it.

Answer (score 0):

actually I had the same problem, You just have to do on dragExit() something like this, to prevent handling dropExit event: event.preventDefault(); That stops propagation of the event and handling dropDrag.